# Find the disc of convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{k}z^{k}$, where $a_{0}=1$ and $a_{k+1}=2\sqrt{a_{k}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, power-series

I want to find the convergence disc of the power series:
Find the disc of convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{k}z^{k}$, where $a_{0}=1$ and $a_{k+1}=2\sqrt{a_{k}}, \forall k \geq 0$.

Here is my try, but I am not sure if it is correct:

\begin{align}
a_{0} &= 1 &=& 2^{0}\\
a_{1} &= 2 \sqrt{a_{0}} = \sqrt{1} = 2 &=& 2^{1}\\
a_{2} &= 2 \sqrt{a_{1}} = 2 \sqrt{2} &=& 2^{1 + 1/2} \\
a_{3} &= 2 \sqrt{a_{2}} = 2 \sqrt{2 \sqrt{2}} &=& 2^{1 + 1/2 + 1/4}\\
a_{4} &= 2 \sqrt{a_{3}} = 2 \sqrt{2 \sqrt{2 \sqrt{2}}} &=& 2^{1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8}\\
\vdots
\end{align}

Then, we see: $a_{k+1} = 2^{\sum_{n=0}^{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}}$. Note that:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k} = \frac{1}{1-1/2}=2
\end{align}

Then, $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_{k+1} = 2^{2}=4$.

Using Cauchy-Hadamard theorem, we define $\frac{1}{\rho}= \text{lim sup} \sqrt[k]{|a_{k}|} = \inf_{n\geq 1}\{\sup_{k\geq n}\{1, 4\}\} = 4$
Therefore, the convergence disc is $D_{1/4}(0)$

Is this "proof" correct?

Comment: $\limsup \sqrt[k]{|a_k|}=\lim \sqrt[k]{|a_k|}=1$, since $|a_k|=a_k$ converges to $4$ and thus its $k$th root converges to $1$.

Comment: You do not need to determine the exact formula for $a_n.$ We certainly have $a_n\ge 1.$ On the other hand $a_n\le 4$ by induction argument. Therefore $a_n^{1/n}\to 1.$ 

The above can be extended to any initial condition. Indeed for $0<a_0\le 4$ we can prove by induction that $2\sqrt{a_0}\le a_n\le 4$ for $n\ge 1.$ For $a_0>4$ we can show by induction that $4\le a_n\le 2\sqrt{a_0}$ for $n\ge 1.$

Answer (score 0):

For convergence, 
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left |\frac{a_{k+1}.z^{k+1}}{a_k. z^k} \right | <1$$
$\implies \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left |2^{\sum_{n=0}^{k+1} (1/2)^n-\sum_{n=0}^{k} (1/2)^n}\right |.|z|<1$
$\implies \color{red}{|z|<1}$